# Carbon retention patterns not being matched

Tags: design-patterns, graphite

I have the following in my storage-schemas.conf

```
[collectd]
pattern = ^machine\.
retentions = 60s:1d, 1m:14d

[grinder]
pattern = ^grinder\.
retentions = 10s:2d, 1m:14d

[catchall]
pattern = ^.*
retentions = 10s:2d, 1m:14d
```

But only the `[catchall]` is being matched against names like `machine.super_foo.cpu.0.cpu.nice`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I am using an older version of Carbon that I thought and the new notation is not supported:

> Additionally, whisper supports a legacy retention specification for
>   backwards compatibility reasons -
>   seconds-per-datapoint:count-of-datapoints
>
> retentions = 60:1440
>
> 60 represents the number of seconds per datapoint, and 1440 represents
>   the number of datapoints to store. This required some unnecessarily
>   complicated math, so although it’s valid, it’s not recommended.

http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config-carbon.html

I used this script to validate the config:

https://github.com/graphite-project/carbon/blob/master/bin/validate-storage-schemas.py

Answer (score 1):

Try-
`pattern = ^machine\.*`

Most probably, your issue is the following, (based of-course on my assumptions)-
You are verifying the header catching the metric by looking at the granularity of the data-points in the webapp. There is a downside to this. This storage schema is used once per .wsp file creation. So while running your tests if it matched `catchall`, it will continue to store it in that schema forever until Grandalf returns.

The workaround is that you delete the .wsp files of your test metrics which would be- 
`/opt/graphite/storage/whisper/stats/machine/super_foo/cpu/0/cpu/nice.wsp` if you're spinning it with defaults.